# Interpolate the version of reusable workflow in Github Actions

Tags: github-actions

Any to pass a variable (of sorts) for the version of a reusable workflow

For example ,if I have this workflow:

```
name: caller-workflow
on:
  pull_request:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
# 2
jobs:
  call-the-workflow:
    uses: action-foobar/action-testing/.github/workflows/called_workflow.yml@${{github.ref_name}}
    with:
      TRIGGER_EVENT : ${{ github.event_name }}
```

from the example above

```
`uses: action-foobar/action-testing/.github/workflows/called_workflow.yml@${{github.ref_name}}` using a `${{github.ref_name}}`
```

instead of a pinned reference.

Would like to be able to call the reusable workflow, using a reference (Thereby I could do easy automation on pull requests or any branch (for pipeline or CI development)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - it's impossible unfortunately.